# How do I change the dtype of a pandas series?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I am attempting to work on a data set from the Museum of modern art and wish to convert some of the series to integer values (for calculations later on). I have tried to convert the dtype using the .astype method but I've been unsuccessful. I saw somewhere that you can do this in the same line of code as the open csv operation, so I attempted it, although unsuccessfully.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('artworks.csv', dtype ={'BeginDate': int})

df.head()


df.dtypes
```

> TypeError       Traceback (most recent call last)
>   pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(1947)'

Ultimately, my goal is to convert the BeginDate and EndDate columns (which are object types) to integers. So as an alternative I tried to write a function to remove the parentheses from the dates and also convert the dates to integers. This is below;

```
def date_cleaner(date):
    if date != "":

        date = date.replace("(", "")
        date = date.replace(")", "")
        date = int(date)

    return (date)

date_cleaner(1999)
```

But this also returned an error when I ran the code. However, when I put in ('1999') as an argument, the code works as it should. The issue is that when I use the function on the pandas series (during an iteration for example) I am returned with the error below;

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    birth_date = row[3]
    death_date = row[4]

    birth_date = date_cleaner(birth_date)
    death_date = date_cleaner(death_date)

    row[3] = birth_date
    row[4] = death_date

df.head()
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-dbecb2797a53> in <module>
      3     death_date = row[4]
      4 
----> 5     birth_date = date_cleaner(birth_date)
      6     death_date = date_cleaner(death_date)
      7 

<ipython-input-51-3ddccbf04d24> in date_cleaner(date)
      6     if date != "":
      7 
----> 8         date = date.replace("(", "")
      9         date = date.replace(")", "")
     10         date = int(date)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

What am I doing wrong and how I can actually clean the columns and convert the dtype?

P.S I have tried to look into the regex method but I am new to python and it seems quite technical

Comment: Replacing a string: `df['A'].str.replace(')','')`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried the code you suggested and it worked in getting one bracket out but left the other. Also, the modifications don't seem to be permanent (i.e, not in place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use str.strip method then as type int

```
df['BeginDate'] = df['BeginDate'].astype(str).str.strip('()').astype(int)
```

Acutlly the full example might clear it up more here:

```
In [10]: df = pd.DataFrame( data = [ {'BeginDate' : '(1948)' } ] )

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
  BeginDate
0    (1948)

In [12]: df['BeginDate'] = df['BeginDate'].astype(str).str.strip('()').astype(int)

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
   BeginDate
0       1948

In [14]:
```

Edit:

Answer to your keeping null_values intact question:

```
In [43]: def clean_year(begin_date):
    ...:     if not  pd.isnull(begin_date):
    ...:         return int(str(begin_date).strip('()'))
    ...:     return begin_date
    ...:

In [44]: df['BeginDate'] .apply(clean_year)
Out[44]:
0    1948.0
1       NaN
Name: BeginDate, dtype: float64
```

but keep in mind that this will make your columns dtype to float as there is none value in there.

Comment: Thanks Kunal that actually helped a ton. The code works in striping and converting the objects to integers. The only issue it came up with was when dealing with nan values. In an attempt to overcome this is i used the fillna function to replace all the nan values with 0 so that the method you provided could work so thanks again.

That said, do you know of a way I can do the same operation you suggested while not altering the nan values (or even ignoring the nan values)? Much appreciated